# Labview using output multiple times

Tags: output, labview

I have a case structure and inside it I have a Boolean output to a LED. I want to use the LED again in another case, but whenever I try to copy the output it just creates a new one with a new LED. Is there a way to have them go to the same LED? I will also need to do this with the inputs, but I am guessing that it is a similar procedure.I cant wire it to the outside, because I need it to change it while it is inside some other loops. An image of the program is below. Sorry that it is messy this is my first code. Thank you for your help.

Current Use of LED:
[image: Current Use of LED:]
Where I want to add it:
[image]

If it is not possible please let me know as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is use local variables. If you right-click on the LEDs and select Create>Local Variable it will allow you to write to them in more than one place.

But Caution: If you do this a lot your code will get very difficult to work with. In this case, you have no choice since you can't place them in one place where they can wired from both sources but I always recommend trying to wire them first if you can.

Answer (score 0):

What jamesmc86 says is correct.

However, to give you a complete overview, and if you want to use a tool that has already a built-in error terminal, you could use [property nodes](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/glang/property_node/). In this case, you should select `Value` property node.

Check them out, they are very powerful and allow you to change all properties of a control/indicator.